# PHP output contains two spaces even no results found

Tags: php, mysql

I use below php code to send results of MYSQL databse search to AJAX requests...

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT name FROM search WHERE qurl = '" . $queryString . "'");


if($query) {

    while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {             
           echo $result->name; 
    }
} else { echo 'no results found'; }
```

but I never get **no results found** message even there is no results, all I get if there is no result, `two empty spaces` - I found that using alert(data.length) in AJAX page, result was 2 which means php output has two empty spaces when there is no results...

but when there are results it works fine...

any way of removing these two spaces or why Im not getting **no results found** message?

Comment: I do hope `$queryString` is properly sanitized, because if it isn't, you're missing the whole point, and should be using prepared statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
  while ...
} else {
  echo 'no results found';
}
```

`$db->query()` only returns `false` if there was an error performing the query. An empty result set is not an error.

Comment: Yes, I tried it before but I get this error..

Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::num_rows() in C:\wamp\www\7\load.php on line 18

Comment: Corrected. It's a property, not a method.

Answer (score 0):

What you are evaluating is if the statement is valid... which it is, and will always return true.  To evaluate the results returned, you'll need to evaluate $query->num_rows

Comment: I tried using num_row but I get a error.. error is Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::num_rows() in C:\wamp\www\7\load.php on line 18

Comment: The answer above had parenthesis... make sure you don't have those.  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php